# android launch zxing scanner only after entering fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

I have an app that uses SherlockFragment and hamburger menu by jeremyfeinstein "SlidingMenu"
also my app uses zxing barcode scanner

when I enter a fragment , in the fragment I have a button that launches the barcode scanner,

but what I need is that when the fragment enters, to launch the scanner,
then when the scanner view gets dismissed, dont do anything,

the problem is that now i have my

> scan();

inside

> onCreateView

so when the scanner gets dismissed it fires again,

here some code,

in PhoneMenuList.java ,,, the fragment gets called:

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment, int index) {
    if (getActivity() == null)
        return;
    /*
              // doesnt work
    if (newContent instanceof PhoneValidateView) {
        ((PhoneValidateView) newContent).scan();
    }
    */

    MainActivityPhone change = (MainActivityPhone) getActivity();
    change.switchContent(newContent);       
}
```

then on PhoneValidateView.java

```
     public class PhoneValidateView extends SherlockFragment{

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
                scan();

}
 ... }
```

so how to show the "scan()" only when fragment loaded by table? not every time fragment appears?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a state to your fragment and only call `scan()` when it is in inital state.

```
private boolean mScannerLaunched = false;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // ...
    mScannerLaunched = savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mScannerLaunched", false);
    if (!mScannerLaunched) {
        scan();
        mScannerLaunched = true;
    }
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    state.putBoolean("mScannerLaunched", mScannerLaunched);
}
```

Comment: hi, just had to make boolean = false, so it doesn't launch a new scanner , thanks!